# Odoo 12 : Change field color (font color) in form view according to condition

Tags: view, odoo-12

I have a field named "status" in my form view, I want to change the color of it to red when the field named "estimated_income" < 50000 else to green. How can i do that in Odoo 12 in from view? 
Thanks.

Comment: using inside <field/> decoration-danger="estimated_income&lt;50000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using inside  decoration-danger="estimated_income<50000"